# Codeigniter 4.0 installation using composer

Tags: php, documentation, codeigniter-4

I have started working on CodeIgniter latest version 4 that supports PHP 7+

I am going through the documentation **installation using composer**, everything seems to be fine expect their one comment under [Cons](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/installation/installing_composer.html#cons) section. What exactly they are referring to? What checks we should monitor?.

```
**Cons**

You still need to check for app/Config changes after updating
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how you install Codeigniter, you will need to configure it to work as you want it to. Most of the config classes are in app/Config. The word 'check' is misleading you in that regard :)

For example connecting it to specific database is done via app/Config/Database.php . Another example would be url of the project - configured in app/Config/App.php .

Not sure when installing with composer if the update would be really easy tho, since you will still may need to reconfigure some of the classes. Another way to handle updates would be to use git, but it is different from what you are asking.